How to connect this wire to this connector?
I am new to electronics and am unsure how to connect the signal & ground wires to this connector, as shown in the picture. Any help would be appreciated

Usually with that wire I see in the corner, you would cut the tinned section of shield braid and strip the outer jacket back to give a section of bare braid that can be folded back and crimped under the long prong. The center conductor can be lap soldered to the inner side of the short prong so it doesn't interfere with screwing the handle/cover back on. Trying to use the little hole in the prong is usually more trouble than it's worth. Sometimes I wrap a little piece of electrical tape around the solder joint if things are tight.

The center conductor should be soldered, while the shield can be soldered or crimped to the ground connector. If you have the appropriate crimp tool, that's probably preferred, but if not, just solder to both of them.
